# Local migration from sqlite to postgres with Flask

Tags: python, postgresql, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-migrate

[image]

I'm trying to extend the flask-base project https://github.com/hack4impact/flask-base/tree/master/app .

I have used flask-migrate to create migrations for my local sqlite db.

I now need to migrate from the local sqlite db to heroku's postgres. Following https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-best-way-to-copy-my-SQLite-database-to-PostgreSQL-so-I-can-deploy-it-to-Heroku , I'm trying I set up a local postgres db called 'test' (screenshot)

I set:

```
os.environ["TEST_DATABASE_URL"] = "postgresql+psycopg2://127.0.0.1:5432/test"   # REMOVE THIS !!!!!!!!!!
```

There is a test config in the config.py containing:

```
class TestingConfig(Config):
    TESTING = True
    SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI = os.environ.get('TEST_DATABASE_URL') or \
        'sqlite:///' + os.path.join(basedir, 'data-test.sqlite')

    print('TestingConfig - psgres?')
    print(SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI)

    WTF_CSRF_ENABLED = False
```

However when I perform the upgrade with flask-migrate:

```
$ python manage.py db upgrade


TestingConfig - psgres?
postgresql+psycopg2://127.0.0.1:5432/test

INFO  [alembic.runtime.migration] Context impl SQLiteImpl.
INFO  [alembic.runtime.migration] Will assume non-transactional DDL.
INFO  [alembic.runtime.migration] Running upgrade  -> 78401e355127, empty message
```

A new sqlite db is created. Obviously I'm not connecting to the postgres test db. How can I get this working?

Comment: https://suhas.org/sqlalchemy-tutorial/

Answer (score 1):

in this case the environmental variables were not being recognized initially, but when I rebooted later they did start working.

```
os.environ["TEST_DATABASE_URL"] = "postgresql://postgres@127.0.0.1:5432/postgres"
```

worked.

Answer (score 0):

I was also doing the migration and I've recorded it in short post:

[Migrating form SqlLite to Postgresql in Flask](https://lukaszherok.com/post/view/8/Migrating%20form%20SqlLite%20to%20Postgresql%20in%20Flask)